# How Many Ways To Sort in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

When I'm working in a Google Spreadsheet, I always use the same routine to perform a sort.

Are there more ways to sort, that lead to Rome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four ways for you to perform a sort. See list below in no particular order:

### First (sheet)

Add the build-in filter function, by pressing the funnel and selecting the first row:
[image]
Then select the green down arrow in columnA, followed by descending (Z --> A):

[image]

### Second (sheet)

Use this formula, on another sheet, to perform the sort you want:

```
=SORT('Build-in SORT'!A2:D,1,0)
```

Syntax of the sort is: `SORT(range, column, sorting order)`

### Third (sheet)

With the usage of a script, complex sorting is possible as well. This one creates a menu item called `Extra`, containing an item called Sort:

```
function onOpen () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menu = [{name: "Sort", functionName: "mySort"}];
  ss.addMenu("Extra", menu);
}

function mySort() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[2].getRange("A2:D")
    .sort({column: 1, ascending: false});
}
```

Goto Tools, Script Editor, from the menu and add the script. Make sure to press the two buttons:

[image]

### Fourth (sheet)

Select column A and choose Data from the menu. Select "Sort sheet by **Column A**, Z --> A"

[image]

Make sure to fix the first row (otherwise the header will join the sort....) !!

### Example File

I've prepared the following example file: **[Four Different Sorts](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdHVwNHdxMHU1eUhKb2ZJZkdsNHN2OFE&usp=sharing)**